merge a sed command on a file with another file
I have a test1.txt file like this
Hello
My name is NAME

and a test2.txt file like this :
Goodbye

and a variable like this :
NAME=bob

I want to use sed on the test1.txt file to replace NAME by "bob" then merge the result to the text2.txt in order to get :
Hello
My name is bob
Goodbye

For the first part I do :
NAME=bob
sed '$ s/NAME$/'$NAME'/' test1.txt

The result is :
Hello
My name is bob

Then I dont know how to merge this sed with my test2.txt file.
This command line :
sed '$ s/NAME$/'$NAME'/' test1.txt test2.txt

gives :
Hello
My name is NAME
Goodbye

without replacing NAME...
Thanx for your help

Try this: sed -s "\$s/NAME\$/$NAME/" test1.txt test2.txt

when is doubt, try the --debug option. You'd've seen it wasn't treating the last line of the first file as the last line, which is why you need --separate.

That task could be done some combination of clearer, simpler, more portably and more robustly using awk. You might want to ask a question about how to do the task rather than how to implement a solution using sed.

-s was the solution, thank you
